# Algorithm to sort data by ratings (considering the chance to show new entires)

Tags: database, algorithm, sorting

I curently have to create a list of IDs (People who offer services) which is sorted.

The list shows the top 10 IDs and it considers the amount of ratings, the rating itself and the date of the last rating (to avoid having very old entries)

That worked fine from the beginning, but my **problem** is:

Now with some IDs getting a lot of ratings, all new IDs have no chance to be diplayed in the first screen and therefore are not getting any attention, bookings and new ratings.

Which brings me to my **question**:

Do you have an idea, how to set up an algorithm where the new entries are considered in an fair way? Or do you have any exmaples or similar questions here in mind? I didn't find anything so far.

Thank you in advance.